# Looking for proof that $SO(3)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

It seems to be taken for granted in all sources that $SO(3)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^9$.  However, the one proof of this that I have been able to find has a step or two that doesn't make alot of sense to me.  (In Frankel, "The Geometry of Physics", if anyone's interested.)  Can anyone point me to -- or even supply right here -- a clear proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof:

1. It's homogeneous. In fact, multiplication by $\mathbf A$ takes a neighborhood of $\mathbf I$ to a neighborhood of $\mathbf A$ by an isometry, for any $\mathbf A \in \mathbf SO(3)$. So you need only prove it's manifold-like at $\mathbf I$.
2. It's manifold-like at $\mathbf I$. For this, use the implicit function theorem. That says that if you have a map $F: \mathbb R^9 \to \mathbb R^6$ that's regular at $I$, then the preimage near $\mathbf I$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$. The map we'll use consists of $6$ components: the dot product of the $i$th column with the $j$th column for $(i, j) = (1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)$. The first three make sure that the columns are unit vectors; the second three that the columns are orthogonal to one another. Clearly $F^{-1}(0,0,0,0,0,0) = O(3)$. To finish things up, you have to show that $F$ is regular at $\mathbf I$, i.e., that $DF(\mathbf I)$ has rank 6. I leave this to you, since it's a simple computation.
3. Note that this also proves that $O(3)$ is a manifold, by the same reasoning, more or less. SO(3) is just the connected component of the identity.

Comment: How come $O(3)$ is a manifold? It is not even connected.

Comment: Not every manifold is connected. For instance, the integers, within the real line, constitute a 0-dimensional manifold with infinitely many components. And more simply, $S^0$, the 0-sphere, consists of the two numbers $\{+1, -1\}$.

Comment: I do not think this is true, the integers is not locally homeomorphic to any Euclidean space. Similarly $S^{0}$ is not a manifold but two points with discrete topology.

Comment: I can assure you that each individual integer (with the subspace topology from $\mathbb R$, namely, that integer is, itself, an open set) is homeomorphic to the manifold $\{0\} = \mathbb R^0$; similarly, you'll find that each of the two points of $S^0$ is homeomorphic to this. You can also see that [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) points out that any discrete space is a 0-dimensional topological manifold.

Comment: Now I see. I did not thought about $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ at here.

Comment: "Manifold" is (mostly) a local definition: the essential feature, that every point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ (possibly $0$!), is a local property, and in particular it cannot be sensitive to a global property like how many connected components a space has. This is a completely separate point from the point that $n$ is also allowed to be $0$.

Comment: @John  OK, I guess I'm just going to have to admit it to myself and everyone else: I'm in over my head.  In math, I've done partial diff eqs and some complex analysis (contour integrals and the like).  That's about as far as I've gone.  What do I need to look at to fill in the gap between where I am and where I need to be to understand your proof?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to not answer sooner. I was away. I should have checked your level of knowledge before answering. To make sense of this proof, you need: the definition of "manifold," a clear understanding of the implicit/inverse function theorems in several dimensions, and a little knowledge of homogeneity. For the first two, some would recommend Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. I love it, but it's too dense for self-study. The first chapter or two of O'Neill's Elementary Differential Geometry might work.  I don't feel confident recommending anything. Maybe someone else can make a good suggestion.